# pdfpages always gives "missing number"

Tags: pdfpages

I have spent *hours* trying to get `pdfpages` to work.

A simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\errorcontextlines 10000
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{an.pdf}
\end{document}
```

doesn't compile. What might be wrong here?

Here is the `.log` file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) (format=pdflatex 2014.1.8)  15 OCT 2017 01:09
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**foo
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
Package: pdfpages 2012/08/31 v0.4t Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/home/ACAD/naiman/UNIX/jctstaff/naiman/styfiles/calc.sty
Style Option: `calc' 3.7 <1993/09/26 19:56:43> (KKT and FJ)
\global@count=\count87
\local@count=\count88
\global@dimen=\dimen103
\local@dimen=\dimen104
\global@skip=\skip43
\local@skip=\skip44
\global@muskip=\muskip10
\local@muskip=\muskip11
\ratio@count=\count89
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2010/10/06 v2.0c eso-pic (RN)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
\Gread@gobject=\count90
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pppdftex.def
File: pppdftex.def 2012/08/31 v0.4t Pdfpages driver for pdfTeX (AM)
)
\AM@pagebox=\box26
\AM@toc@title=\toks15
\c@AM@survey=\count91
\AM@templatesizebox=\box27
)
(./foo.aux)
\openout1 = `foo.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box28
 (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count92
\scratchdimen=\dimen107
\scratchbox=\box29
\nofMPsegments=\count93
\nofMParguments=\count94
\everyMPshowfont=\toks16
\MPscratchCnt=\count95
\MPscratchDim=\dimen108
\MPnumerator=\count96
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count97
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks17
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
<an.pdf, id=3, page=1, 597.23125pt x 845.1575pt>
File: an.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
 <use an.pdf, page 1>
Package pdftex.def Info: an.pdf, page1 used on input line 5.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 597.22978pt x 845.15544pt.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
\next ->\egroup \global 
                        \@tempa \@tempb \egroup \global \@tempa \@tempb \pos...

\post@scan ...err #1\fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \next 
                                                  #2
\generic@assign ...dafter \@open \expandafter (#4!
                                                  \global \@tempa \@tempb \e...

\AM@output ...setlength {\@tempdima }{\AM@xscale }
                                                  \edef \AM@xscale {\strip@p...

\\includepdf ...er {\AM@pagestemp }\AM@output {#1}
                                                  \fi \AM@CheckAtEnd \endgro...
l.5 ...agecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{an.pdf}

? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2671 strings out of 493315
 38243 string characters out of 6137911
 100704 words of memory out of 5000000
 6118 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 38i,6n,39p,232b,213s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 3 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 16 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Thank you for your replies.  I have waited until the sysadmin could update TeX Live, and I also downloaded a simple PDF file ([pdf-sample.pdf](http://che.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pdf-sample.pdf)).  Unfortunately, I still have the same problem, and would most appreciate if someone would help me discern what the complaint is in the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.10.18)  21 OCT 2017 20:37
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**foo
(./foo.tex
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pdfpages.sty
Package: pdfpages 2017/08/14 v0.5k Insert pages of external PDF documents (AM)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/home/ACAD/naiman/UNIX/jctstaff/naiman/styfiles/calc.sty
Style Option: `calc' 3.7  (KKT and FJ)
\global@count=\count87
\local@count=\count88
\global@dimen=\dimen103
\local@dimen=\dimen104
\global@skip=\skip43
\local@skip=\skip44
\global@muskip=\muskip10
\local@muskip=\muskip11
\ratio@count=\count89
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2015/07/21 v2.0g eso-pic (RN)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2017/06/24 v1.0g Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen105
\Gin@req@width=\dimen106
)
\AM@pagewidth=\dimen107
\AM@pageheight=\dimen108

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfpages/pppdftex.def
File: pppdftex.def 2017/08/14 v0.5k Pdfpages driver for pdfTeX (AM)
)
\AM@pagebox=\box26
\AM@global@opts=\toks15
\AM@toc@title=\toks16
\c@AM@survey=\count90
\AM@templatesizebox=\box27
)
(./foo.aux)
\openout1 = `foo.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box28

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count91
\scratchdimen=\dimen109
\scratchbox=\box29
\nofMPsegments=\count92
\nofMParguments=\count93
\everyMPshowfont=\toks17
\MPscratchCnt=\count94
\MPscratchDim=\dimen110
\MPnumerator=\count95
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count96
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks18
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/pdflscape.sty
Package: pdflscape 2016/05/14 v0.11 Display of landscape pages in PDF (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty
Package: lscape 2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
)
Package pdflscape Info: Auto-detected driver: pdftex on input line 81.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
))

File: pdf-sample.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

Package pdftex.def Info: pdf-sample.pdf  used on input line 5. on input line 5.

Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 597.22978pt x 845.15544pt on input lin
e 5.
File: pdf-sample.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

Package pdftex.def Info: pdf-sample.pdf  used on input line 5. on input line 5.

Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 597.22978pt x 845.15544pt on input lin
e 5.

File: pdf-sample.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)

Package pdftex.def Info: pdf-sample.pdf , page1 used on input line 5. on input
line 5.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 597.22978pt x 845.15544pt on input lin
e 5.

! Missing number, treated as zero.

                   \global
\next ->\egroup \global
                        \@tempa \@tempb \egroup \global \@tempa \@tempb \pos...

\post@scan ...err #1\fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \next
                                                  #2
\generic@assign ...dafter \@open \expandafter (#4!
                                                  \global \@tempa \@tempb \e...

\AM@output ...setlength {\@tempdima }{\AM@xscale }
                                                  \edef \AM@xscale {\strip@p...

\\includepdf ...ndafter {\the \AM@global@opts ,#1}
                                                  \fi \AM@CheckAtEnd \endgro...
l.5 ...nd={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{pdf-sample.pdf}

? x

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2699 strings out of 492990
 39138 string characters out of 6132620
 100175 words of memory out of 5000000
 6240 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,6n,39p,266b,221s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 4 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 21 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me (exept from the change to `empty` I made in the pagestyle to avoid overlapping page numbers)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your version of TeX Live is severely outdated (2013), this might be part of the problem, although it is difficult to tell without having access to the `an.pdf` file you are trying to include. Your code itself seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a really ancient version of [`calc`](https://ctan.org/pkg/calc) lingering in `/home/ACAD/naiman/UNIX/jctstaff/naiman/styfiles/calc.sty`: the log file shows

> ```
> Style Option: `calc' 3.7 <1993/09/26 19:56:43> (KKT and FJ)
> ```

which is not even a LaTeX2e package, but an old LaTeX 2.09 style option. Using [this historic file](http://www.csee.ogi.edu/support/unix/latex/inputs209/calc.sty) in a modern TeX distribution I can reproduce your error message.

Just get rid of the file, or at least move it to a place where it isn't found by LaTeX, and your problem should be solved as the current version of the package will be used instead automatically.

Comment: Thanx so much for taking the time, and pointing this out!  -- ATB, Aharon